# Anyone has any ideas how can .NET framework work on Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

According to this site [Click here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/issues/5), the participant said that Oxford's Speech-to-text with universal apps isn't be released yet. And now, I am working with my project required Universal Windows Platform.

Since SpeechClient.dll of Project Oxford is .NET framework, I cannot add it as reference to my Universal Windows project which supports only .NET core. I've been trying to find a solution from existing questions. Eventually I end up here.

Does anyone has an idea to apply this .NET Framework DLL?

Portable Class Library is a good choice for now?

Cheers,

Comment: UWP targets .NETCore, a *much* smaller version of the framework.  A fairly inevitable choice because of the U, only small amounts of software are ever easy to make Universal.  That project surely depends on SAPI, it isn't available on mobile devices.  They get hard to carry when they have to support everything that a desktop machine does.